# Import/Export CMS Pages / CMS Blocks

Tags: import, cms

Does anyone know any modules that can be used to import/export cms pages (and blocks) in CE?

The scenario I am looking at now is:

- users (content editors) create pages/blocks with content on a staging website (cloned after live site, different db, different servers)
- after the pages are being validated, the users create the pages again on the live site (copy-pasting)

Some things to take into consideration:

- it shoudn't keep a reference to the store views by IDs, rather use the store view code
- duplicate pages on import should be identified by url key and store views

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On the last Hackathon we developed a module which will help you to achieve this:

https://github.com/magento-hackathon/firegento-contentsync

It will store the content in a json file, which can be synced to another server (already integrated are git and svn support).
It still uses the store views by ID, but pull requests are strongly appreciated. ;)

Comment: Can you please, provide a Wiki page for this module. This looks quite awesome. Thank you very much :D

Comment: Buddy, Question is **How to Import some CMS pages from ONE magento site to ANOTHER, this is waste of time as it syncs thru GIT,SVN**. Please answer the question anked.

Comment: Currently this extension is abandoned.

Answer (score 6):

You can do export/import cms pages/static blocks easily via SSH.

1. Export:

   ```
   mysqldump -u [username] -p[password] [database] cms_page cms_page_store cms_block cms_block_store | grep INSERT | sed 's/INSERT INTO/REPLACE INTO/' > cms-export.sql
   ```

   > **Note:** Don’t forget to add prefix to cms_* tables if you have prefixed your tables.
2. Import:

   ```
   mysql -u [username] -p[password] [database] < cms-export.sql
   ```

**[ Make sure to backup your database before any import operation ]**

REF: http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/export-import-cms-pages-static-blocks-via-ssh/

Comment: this assumes that live is not changed in the meantime... everything gets overwritten.

Comment: It will not export the static content, which is not in DB and only in files.

Comment: MageAnts magento 2 extensions provider company selling [cms import export extension](https://www.mageants.com/cms-import-export-extension-for-magento-2.html) will work